# Summing particular rows in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have following data where I want to add only "Total" column yearly(12 rows at once). How to do it with `pandas` ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) for new column:

```
df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'], dayfirst=True)

df['yearly'] = df.groupby(df['datum'].dt.year)['Total'].transform('sum')
```

If want new DataFrame aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['datum'].dt.year.rename('Year'))['Total'].sum().reset_index()
```